# cual es problema de mi codigo en

Tags: javascript

Hola hice este ejercicio con funciones donde el usuario ingresa números para sacar la media de estos. El ciclo se rompera cuando se ingresa un numero negativo y saca la media. Sin embargo el codigo no funciona. Ya he intentado todo y no funciona. Por favor ayudenme

```js
'use stritc'
    
    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    
        alert("amatesaurius");
    
        function domingo(suma, contador, numero){
    
        var suma = 0;
        var contador = 0;
    
        var numero = parseInt(prompt("Escribe tu numero hasta que escribas una negarivo: ", 0));
    
            do{
    
                if(isNaN(numero)){
                    numero = 0;
                }else if(numero >= 0){
                    suma = suma + numero;
                    contador++;
                }
    
            }while(numero >= 0)
    
            document.write("La suma de todos los numeros es: " + suma);
        document.write("La media de la suma es: " + (suma/2));
    
        domingo(suma, contador, numero);
    
        }
    
    });
```

Comment: `'use stritc'` tiene un typo

Answer (score 0):

- La función domingo está dentro de la función domingo. Entonces nunca se llama
- Además los argumentos de esta función son innecesario en tu caso.
- El prompt debería ir dentro del do while
- Preferir usar Number por sobre parseInt
- La media debe dividirse por "contador"
- Además es `use strict` no `use stritc` (Gracias @Mateo)

```js
'use strict'
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  function domingo(){
    let suma = 0;
    let contador = 0;
    let numero =0;
        
    do
    {
       numero = Number(prompt("Escribe tu numero hasta que escribas una negarivo: ", 0));
       
       if(isNaN(numero)){
          numero = 0;
       }
       else if(numero >= 0){
          suma = suma + numero;
          contador++;
       }
    
    }while(numero >= 0)
    
    document.write("La suma de todos los numeros es: " + suma);
    document.write("La media de la suma es: " + (suma/contador));
    
 }
 domingo();
});
```

Comment: Es `use strict`

Comment: muchas gracias. ya funciona